# Terminate Own Process at Catch Exception

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I want to terminate my own code at exception, is this possible?

Below is the code and its not working, please help.

```
            try
            {
                rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rj.KeySize = 256;
                rj.BlockSize = 256;
                rj.Key = Key;
                rj.IV = IV;
                var ms = new MemoryStream(cypher);

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                    {
                        sRet = sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
               Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
            finally
            {
                rj.Clear();
            }
```

That is giving error if the text to process is not base_64, and I want to close the application if its encountered that error. The reason why I want to close it is because, it only means the user is trying to use fake serial key.

Comment: thanks @zmbq, now i am able to test my code and its not closing.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class is in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

The way to find that out is to look for '.NET Process class' in your [favorite search engine.](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=.net+process+class&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.Exit` would also work.